# What's the name of the highlight group for the number column?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

The one with the numbers that looks grey ? I already got the fold with this.

```
hi FoldColumn guibg=#000000 guifg=#ffffff
```

I just don't know what the name if that numbers column is.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s `LineNr` and `CursorLineNr`.